# Reducing MSQL Query to a specific session

Tags: php, mysql

Using the code below, I was able to display each username and trial 1/0 flag in the table.  What I want to do is display the data only for the existing user so I can say something like "Hello USERNAME, you have TRIAL access..." etc...

We're using standard HTACESS as the un/pass to enter the info area.

What needs to change here to only show the existing user's session?

```
<?PHP

$user_name = "blahblahblah";
$password = "blahblahblah";
$database = "blahblahblah";
$server = "127.0.0.1";

$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if ($db_found) {

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM member_auth";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {

print $db_field['username'] . " : ";
print $db_field['trial'] . " <br> ";

}

mysql_close($db_handle);

}
else {

print "Database NOT Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

please don't use mysql_ functions.. look into PDO or MySQLi here: http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases

Update your query to only return specific user results.

**Using Form POST:**

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
```

**Using URL Parameters:**

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["username"]);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["password"]);
```

**So your SQL query will now look like:**

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM member_auth WHERE username = '" . $username . "' AND password = '" . $password . "'";
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  I will also be looking into PDO / MYSQLi

Comment: I tried the POST and URL / GET methods and changed my SQL query as directed here and get no output now. =[

Comment: What does your member_auth table look like?